# Calculate fundamental group and construct covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Calculate the fundamental group of the tensor product sign,$\otimes$,a subset of a plane,based at the point in the middle of the sign.Exhibit a connected 3- fold covering of this space.

I want to decompose this figure into some circles whose fundamental group is $Z$ and then may integrate them together.But I don't know how to do it.For the second question , I've encountered several such kind of questions and have no method to approach it.Can you recommend some books which I can refer to.

Comment: The tensor product is a wedge of four circles.

Comment: This seems to be an application of the Van Kampen theorem, but maybe there is some "easier" solution.

Comment: @Cla Can you give me some hint about how to use Van Kampen theorem to solve this problem?

Comment: Well I haven't said that this is the solution, but that it can be. I haven't check it, but it seems that you can express the fundamental group of the tensor in terms of the fundamental groups of the circle and the "times" sign (with relations given by the fundamental group of four disjoint points). Does it make sense (and is feasible)?